# Converting EMF Image from MS Word to BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am writing a program that would read text from an image. I have success on JPG/PNG by getting the BufferedImage out of the XWPFPictureData.

```
public static BufferedImage convertPicDataToBuffImg(XWPFPictureData objPicData) {
    byte[] bData = objPicData.getData();
    BufferedImage objInBuffImg = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bData));
    ...
}
```

However, when using the same code for EMF picture types, objInBuffImg becomes null. As I read, this is because the type is EMF.

To use the same methods I used, I wanted to convert XWPFPictureData with PictureType Document.PICTURE_TYPE_EMF to BufferedImage.

So basically what I wanted to do is something like the following:

```
public static BufferedImage convertPicDataToBuffImg(XWPFPictureData objPicData) {
    BufferedIMage objInBuffImg = null;

    if (objPicData.getPictureType() == Document.PICTURE_TYPE_EMF)) {
        // Convert to BufferedImage
    } else {
        byte[] bData = objPicData.getData();
        objInBuffImg = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bData));
    }
    ...
}
```

Have been searching and read about Batik but can't exactly figure out how to do what I want to do as stated above.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: I've created a couple of `ImageIO` plugins that wraps Batik, capable of reading (some) WMF files into `BufferedImage`s, available [here](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys). It's all dependent on Batik's WMF/EMF capabilities though, but if it works for you, you should be able to keep your original code without the extra branch for handling EMF.

Comment: @haraldK Thank you very much. Will try this and will send feedback. :)

Comment: @haraldK When doing mvn install in your project, it gives me the following error. I already tried changing it to use JDK 1.7/1.8, still the same error.

git/TwelveMonkeys/common/common-lang/src/test/java/com/twelvemonkeys/util/CollectionAbstractTest.java:[1139,31] reference to toArray is ambiguous
[ERROR]   both method <T>toArray(T[]) in java.util.Collection and method <T>toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction<T[]>) in java.util.Collection match

Comment: Seems Maven doesn’t pick up your JDK settings and uses a newer JDK, if you get that error. Consult the Maven docs. But there’s no need to build from source unless you make changes. I recommend using the public Maven dependencies. Or use the download links on the project page.